# It is Possible to set the TV remote navigation focus in EPG-GUIDE using Canvas & View Group in android

Tags: android, android-tv, epg

1.I am Developing an android Electronic Program Guide(EPG) application for set-top-box followed by this project "https://github.com/korre/android-tv-epg."

2.I am able to get output(design) like this
[image]

3.I want to get output with  focus of any one cell & From TV Remote navigation for travel to other cells,so i need to set focus of corresponding cell. please advice it,

Comment: check this fork : https://github.com/codessentials/android-tv-epg

Comment: HI,Bertrand Martel,   how to scroll down while press the down button.,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416404/unable-to-scroll-down-in-tvepg-guideusing-tv-remote-down-button