# Unable to scroll down in TV(EPG-GUIDE)Using TV Remote Down Button

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tv, swipe-gesture, epg

1.I am Developing an android application as Electronic Program Guide(EPG) for set-top-box followed by this project https://github.com/codessentials/android-tv-epg."

2.I can able to navigate  left to right,rigtht to left(Horizontal scroll) & able to see the  focus also(Left & right Remote key navigation), [image]

3.I can't navigate Top to Bottom & Bottom to Top,unable to scroll it & can't see the  focus,that view fully opened, so focus went  to down but i can't see that.[image]

4.How to scroll as Top to  buttom(Up & Down Remote key navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html). The Android framework automatically applies a directional navigation scheme based on the relative position of focusable elements in your layouts. You should test the generated navigation scheme in your app using a D-pad controller. After testing, if you decide you want users to move through your layouts in a specific way, you can set up explicit directional navigation for your controls. Check the [lists of all of the available navigation attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html#modify-d-pad-nav) for Android user interface widgets. To use one of these explicit navigation attributes, set the value to the ID (`android:id` value) of another widget in the layout. You should set up the navigation order as a loop, so that the last control directs focus back to the first one.